# How to use build method with a has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**My Models:**

```
class Vip < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :organization
    has_many :events
    has_many :organizations, :through => :events
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :events
    has_many :vips, :through => :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :vip
end
```

**My vips Controller:**

```
def create
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
    @vip = @organization.vips.build(vip_params)

    if @vip.save
        redirect_to organization_path(@organization)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
def vip_params
    params.require(:vip).permit(:name, :about, :organization_id)
end
```

Before I started using the has_many :through associations, the `build` method would automatically add the foreign key to the new vip. So my vips table would have the `organization_id` column populated. Since using the has_many associations, the `organization_id` column is being left NULL on `'vip#create'`.

Is there a reason that `build` wouldn't work the same way anymore with my new associations?

Comment: Why does `Organization` have `has_many :vips, :through => :events` when a `vip` directly `belongs_to` an `organization`?

Comment: Your associations are not very clear. In your `Vip` model you have both `belongs_to :organization` and `has_many :organizations, through: ...`. Do you have `organization_id` in your `Vip` model?

Comment: I agree with the above.  You don't need VIP to belong_to :organization if you have the has_many_through.  You may also need to use accepts_nest_attributes_for in order to use the build method.