# build record with has_many through association, no db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

In the context of testing a method not querying the db when given a preloaded relation, I would like to build a record with preloaded associations. I run into trouble when trying to build a record that has has_many through relations. This doesn't work:

```
let(:preloaded_record) { build(:test_record,
  hmtas: build_list(:has_many_through_association, N)
) }
```

Building a relation by persisting data to the database, then querying the database for this data in order to test that a method doesn't hit the database seems less than optimal.

**How do I build a record with preloaded has_many through associations without using the db?**

Desired: an actual record or close analog, that has .association(:hmtas).loaded?

Optional: using factory_bot

Relates to: [How to use build method with a has_many :through association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231769/how-to-use-build-method-with-a-has-many-through-association)

Comment: Why does it seem less than optimal? The cost is low, you don't have to create a work around, and it more closely approximates a production context.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid hitting db due to performance wherever possible

Comment: What's the performance cost of hitting the db?

Comment: I don't have numbers. It slows down tests. I don't think it is strictly relevant to the question. Maybe I should shorten the context if it distracts? I appreciate any help you can come up with

Comment: See Max's answer. I would be surprised if the db hit would be slowing down tests materially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you don't. ActiveRecord Associations are just an abstraction on top of a relational database and they just don't make sense without it - associations are defined by foreign key relationships.

Thats why associations don't really have a provision for stubbing.

You can [stub](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-7/docs) the getter method to return an array of objects:

```
allow(parent).to receive(:children)
                  .and_return(build_list(:children, 10))
```

But you need to weight the loss of acuity against what might be a very trivial performance boost.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks. I'm still hoping someone will come up with something though

Comment: I would have to say don't get your hopes up. You can stub out the setters and getters to make the "association" behave like a regular ruby attribute but you risk masking bugs and errors in your application. I would say that if your test needs an association your not testing it properly if you stub it out. After all the biggest part of what a model does in AR is represent rows in the DB and shuffle data it in and out.

Comment: For the sake of the argument though, in case I would be running this test a lot of times it would start playing a role. I think it is weird there is no way of doing this. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Its not strange - its intentional. http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/tdd-is-dead-long-live-testing.html

Comment: seems almost like the designers of this are opinionated enough to try and torpedo unit testing by disallowing mocking the database boundary. The feature test I need this for is only interested in the loading aspect and quite important since there are a lot of ways regressions could appear. Leaving the db alone here is a clear advantage

Comment: good read, but with respect it seems opinionated. It links http://www.rbcs-us.com/documents/Why-Most-Unit-Testing-is-Waste.pdf which is a really good read and doesn't make the claim all unit tests are wrong, or that TDD is dead. I think TDD is great as long as tests are written with proper coverage